# how do i pull geotaged tweets in python

Tags: python, twitter

I had a python file that I used to pull geotagged tweets from twitter, but now it requires OAuth. I'm trying to work with 1.1 but I'm not sure what to do next.  My code below is from the  [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples#python), with some minor changes since the documentation is wrong `(force_auth_header=True was removed and set body="")`.

I searched around, but either the posts are outdated or confusing.  I think I'm close, but not sure where to go next.  Ultimately I'd like to use something like `search_url3`, but I know that format is incorrect because I can tell it is getting a 401 error.

In the mean time, if I can get the results in a json format, that'd be great.

I used to use something like this:

```
search = urllib.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&rpp=100&geocode=39.95256,-75.164,2mi)
for result in j["results"]:
    ...
```

My current code:

```
import oauth2 as oauth

consumer_key="123"
consumer_secret="345"
Access_token="567"
Access_token_secret="890"

def oauth_req(url, key, secret, http_method="GET",http_headers=None):
     consumer = oauth.Consumer(key, secret)
     token = oauth.Token(Access_token,Access_token_secret)
     client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
     resp, content = client.request(url,method=http_method,body="",
          headers=http_headers)

     print resp

return content

 search_url2="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=39.95256,-75.164,2mi"
 search_url3="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4"
 home_timeline = oauth_req(search_url3,  consumer_key,  consumer_secret)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, unless this is somekind of homework, you are doing it wrong. there are terrific (and not so terrific) python-twitter libs and wrappers, unless building one is your core mission than use one of them:

- [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter)
- [python-twitter-tools](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter)
- [twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython)
- [tweepy](http://tweepy.github.io/)

Etc..

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I want to use wrappers sparingly.